# jquery loop on textarea text reverse order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reverse

i have textarea with text that is sperated with line break 
i want to loop this list in reverse order?
so if i have text that loop like this

```
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,4
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5
```

it will read from 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5 ... to .... 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
i know i can loop the text area like this :

```
$.each($('textarea[name=source]').val().split('\n'), function(e){
    alert(this);
 });
```

how can i convert it so it read the text in reverse order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `reverse()` directly instead of using a temporary variable to hold your array data.

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/23cygt3v/)

```
$.each($('textarea[name=source]').val().split('\n').reverse(), function(e){
    alert(this);
 });
```

Comment: reverse is not jquery.. it is just javascript.

Comment: once you use `.val()` you are out of the jQuery chain. The `split()` returns a standard array, and `.reverse()` is a method of `Array.prototype`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.reverse()` and loop.

```
var myArray = $('textarea[name=source]').val().split('\n');
myArray.reverse();

$.each(myArray, function(){
    alert(this);
});
```

Comment: if only all programming was so intuitive :)